# Determine if application is running in debug mode without using httpcontext. (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC program you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

In order to determine if `debug="true"` in the web.config.

How do I do this without referring to the HttpContext?

Comment: What are you going to use this value for? The reason I ask is that this value is only relevant in a certain context, which may not be of use for your scenario.

Comment: I hash some scripts on server start, I want to do it in a constructor of a singleton that is required by a few controllers. At the moment I have to do it on the first request because I need the HttpContext because when in debug mode I do things differently.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by server start? Is this a web server start or the actual server start? And are these scripts running as part of a web server that has ASP.NET capabilities?

Comment: Web server start, the server has ASP.NET capabilities

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must read the configuration manually like this:

```
var compilation = (CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/compilation");

if (compilation.Debug)
{
    //Debug is on!
}
```

Comment: The defined DEBUG constant does not tell you what the debug value in the web.config is. You can compile in release mode and still have debug=true. The question specifically asks how to check the value of debug in the web.config.