# MVC Bundle Exclude Files On Debug

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have a bundle which is called like this :

```
Bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/html", "~/Templates", new AngularHtmlCombine()).IncludeDirectory("~/Templates", "*.html", true);
```

The bundle works great in debug=false mode but in debug it includes all my html files in script tags

How can I tell the bundles to not work in debug?

Comment: What code are you using to the bundle in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

when debug=true all the files are separately rendered in script tags. As u have *.html it includes all the the html files in script tags separately.

I am not sure what is the purpose of bundling html files in your case as it is mostly used for css and js.

Adding this line in bundle.config `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` will enable bundling irrespective of the value of debug in web.config  and will combine all your html pages to one file (~/bundles/html) and will not render in script tags

Comment: Yes but its the same as using debug=false. It minifies all my files always

Comment: Sorry when debug = true. Edited my answer. Bundling doesn't work in debug mode because of the thought that u will debug the JavaScript for the control flow.

Comment: Alright, now the information is correct but all I want is to ignore the bundle if we are in debug mode. The purpose of the bundle is to create a single js files with all the templates in $templateCache. I am using custom bundles : http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/10/aspnet-45-mvc-4-revisiting-IBundleTransform-in-bundling.html. I was hoping just changing something there will do the trick

Comment: if u don't want all those html pages to render in script tags or any where just have a check before rendering in your cshtml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865039/determine-if-application-is-running-in-debug-mode-without-using-httpcontext-as

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the bundle was to take all of my template files and put them in a single javascript file using angular's $templateCache.

works great in release mode but in debug it just adds all my .html files as scripts.

The following lines in BundleConfig.cs solved my problem by ignoring HTML files in the bundles :

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.html");
```